# Pass props into TabIcon with React Native Router Flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using `react-native-router-flux` in my app and want to pass in paths to png images for my TabIcon components. I know I could just make a different tab icon component for each tab, but these icons would be exactly the same except for the image source and I want to find a DRY way to accomplish my goal. Where in my scenes can I pass in the image path?

Here is my TabIcon component:

```
const TabIcon = ({ selected, title, image }) => {
  const tabStyle = selected ? styles.selected : styles.unselected
  return (
    <View style={tabStyle}>
      <Image
        style={{height: 35, width: 35}}
        source={require(image)}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

My scenes:

```
const Scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key='root'>
    <Scene key='tabbar' tabs={true} tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}>
      <Scene key='tab1' title='Feed' icon={TabIcon}>
        <Scene 
          key='Feed'
          component={Feed}
          title='Feed'
          initial={true}
        />
      </Scene>
      <Scene key='tab2' title='Create' icon={TabIcon}>
        <Scene
          key='Create'
          component={Create}
          title='Create'
        />
      </Scene>
      <Scene key='tab3' title='Leaderboard' icon={TabIcon}>
        <Scene
          key='leaderboard'
          component={Leaderboard}
          title='Leaderboard' 
        />
      </Scene>
    </Scene>
  </Scene>
)
```

***EDIT***

I have tried passing in the image like so

```
const Scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key='root'>
    <Scene key='tabbar' tabs={true} tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}>
                                                    //HERE
      <Scene key='tab1' title='Feed' icon={TabIcon} image={'../images/feed.png'}>
        <Scene 
          key='matchupsFeed'
          component={MatchupsFeed}
          title='Feed'
          initial={true}
        />
      </Scene>
...
...
...
```

Within my TabIcon component if I `console.log(image)` it prints out `"../images/feed.png"` but I get this error in the simulator:

```
Unknown named module: '../images/feed.png'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713025/requiring-unknown-module-when-i-use-image-to-load-static-resource), I figured it out:

```
const TabIcon = ({ selected, title, image }) => {
  const selectColor = selected ? '#ED1B25' : '#FFF'
  return (
    <View style={[styles.tabStyle, {borderBottomColor: selectColor}]}>
      <Image
        style={{height: 35, width: 35}}
        // Change HERE
        source={image}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Scenes

```
const Scenes = Actions.create(
  <Scene key='root'>
    <Scene key='tabbar' tabs={true} tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}>
                                                   //Change HERE
      <Scene key='tab1' title='Feed' icon={TabIcon} image={require('../images/feed.png')}>
```